# Android Frida hook Constructor?

Tags: android, frida

I am working on android frida to hook in the constructor but it's not calling the constructor from my frida script.

**MyCode:**

**Android**

```
package com.demo.app.test;

public class DemoTest {

    public String v1;
    public int v2;
    public boolean v3;

    public DemoTest(String v1, int v2, boolean v3){
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.v3 = v3;
    }
}
```

**Frida Script - test.js**

```
setTimeout(function() {

Java.perform(function() {

        console.log(" Demo Test")

        var activity = Java.use("com.demo.app.test.DemoTest");

        activity.$init.overload('java.lang.String', 'int', 'boolean').implementation = function(arg0, arg1, arg2) {

            console.log(arg0+" :: "+arg1+" :: "+arg2);

            return this.init.overload('java.lang.String', 'int', 'boolean').call(this,arg0, arg1, arg2);
        }
    });

}, 0);
```

**Frida Command:**

```
frida -U -f com.demo.app -l test.js --no-pause
```

this is the above code. I am not able to call inside the **implementation**, it's not getting any result from the constructor.

please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Based on the [Frida sample code for hooking a constructor](https://github.com/iddoeldor/frida-snippets#hook-constructor) you should better call `return this.$init(arg0, arg1, arg2);`

Comment: thanks @Robert, yes i did the same and it worked :)  Thanks again

Comment: You can close the question ;)