# Frida - NotLoaded Class Hooking - Java.registerClass not working

Tags: java, android, hook, frida

Hy everyone.
I try to hook an not loaded class on android apk with adb and frida. To do that, I try to load the class include in the dex file, with unusual way. I create a new class with Java.registerClass() to load the original with the implemented targeted class.

However when I run the code I should to deal with problems :

1. Firstly, with the all script I receive this following message :

```
{'type': 'error', 'description': "TypeError: cannot read property 'replace' of undefined", 'stack': "TypeError: cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at w (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/types.js:334)
    at registerClass (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:153)
    at registerClass (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:271)
    at bend4 (/script1.js:42)
    at <eval> (/script1.js:48)", 'fileName': 'frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/types.js', 'lineNumber': 334, 'columnNumber': 1}
```

2. When I run only the first line, system send a refusal for needed permission to do the task. The following refusal :

```
{'type': 'error', 'description': 'Error: java.io.IOException: Permission denied', 'stack': 'Error: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/env.js:124)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:1058)
    at e (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:580)
    at apply (native)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:963)
    at e (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:547)
    at ue (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:1190)
    at fromBuffer (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:1168)
    at registerClass (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:216)
    at registerClass (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:271)
    at bend4 (/script1.js:42)
    at <eval> (/script1.js:48)', 'fileName': 'frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/env.js', 'lineNumber': 124, 'columnNumber': 1}
```

I specify I run the hook with root privilege on Android VM based on virtualbox devices.

The hook script :

```
function bend4(){
    const p2 = Java.registerClass({

        name:"com.example.orl",
        // implements: [],
        // superClass: targeted_class,

    });

    const p3 = p2.$new();
    send(p3);
};
Java.perform(bend4());
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: why are you tagging python

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake but this hook is include in python script with the Frida Python Bindings. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The [Android implementation of RegisterClass](https://github.com/frida/frida-java-bridge/blob/main/lib/class-factory.js) doesn't override classes already present in the JVM. It adds new classes, or fails when one already exists - probably what you see here. You can use it to [extend existing classes](https://github.com/frida/frida-java-bridge/blob/main/test/re/frida/ClassCreationTest.java), ofc, but I'm not sure that's what you're after.

To modify the behavior of an existing class, you can try [Java.use](https://frida.re/docs/examples/android/) to hook the class behavior before generation and [generate new instances](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/272) or [hook the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727552/android-frida-hook-constructor). There are other modes like [Java.choose](https://frida.re/docs/examples/android/) to find and modify instances in memory, stalker, intercept, spy...

For example:

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var orl_class = Java.use('com.example.orl')
    var orl_instance = orl_class.$new();
    send(orl_instance.toString());
});
```